# MongoDB (java) takes a long time for a find

Tags: java, performance, mongodb

I have a mongdb database with the following stats:

```
{
        "ns" : "pourmoi.featurecount",
        "count" : 12152142,
        "size" : 1361391264,
        "avgObjSize" : 112,
        "numExtents" : 19,
        "storageSize" : 1580150784,
        "lastExtentSize" : 415174656,
        "paddingFactor" : 1,
        "paddingFactorNote" : "paddingFactor is unused and unmaintained in 3.0.
It remains hard coded to 1.0 for compatibility only.",
        "userFlags" : 1,
        "capped" : false,
        "nindexes" : 2,
        "totalIndexSize" : 1165210816,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 690111632,
                "feature_1" : 475099184
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

and a java program that does a `find` and returns around 50 results.

This is the query

```
db.featurecount.find(
{ "$or" : [ { "feature" : "hello"}, { "feature" : "how"},
            { "feature" : "are"} , { "feature" : "you"} ]})
.sort({count: -1}).limit(20)
```

This query takes around 30 seconds (at least)... Is it possible to make it run faster?

PS: The mongodb server is in localhost...

Comment: If I remove the sort/limit, it takes around 2 minutes with around 2500 results...

Comment: Lots of documents here. is this sharded? If so then the shard key is certainly not your search term here. Seems like a lot of storage on a low memory machine. Or at least this query is not within the normal working set of memory.

Comment: Use query explain feature to get information about various stats of the query http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/ . It is better to try it from a mongo shell than doing it from a Java program to understand the performance issues. Also the index size is huge, around 1 GB. If the index doesn't fit in memory, the query may be slow.